# New Official Icon for Android Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

How can I use Google's new icon?  Is this a resource?  Or something you can add in code, such as:

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(showHomeAsUp)
```

Here is picture from dev site (note:  It's the "3 Lines" that I am seeking):

[image]

Comment: That might be the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html

Comment: That does indeed look like it.  Now looking to see how to implement...

Comment: Well, I am using the `SlidingMenu` library by `jfeinstien`, so this may not work to incorporate this to that?  I was assuming this would be a separate element.

Comment: I certainly would not assume that. That being said, the code should be in AOSP, and so somebody could poke around and find where the icon is and perhaps figure out how to use it with third-party sliding menu implementations.

Comment: hi.. can i use Android Navigation Drawer in Android < 3.0 ,using any support lib ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The icon is available for [download](https://developer.android.com/downloads/design/Android_Design_Icons_20131106.zip) in the Android developers [downloads](https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html) section. Find it at `/Navigation_Drawer_Indicator` in the ZIP file.

[image: Drawer icon]

If you are looking for the new material navigation drawer icon, you can find it in the official [Material Design Icons](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons) in different colors and sizes, for example at [navigation/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_menu_black_24dp.png](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/navigation/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_menu_black_24dp.png).

[image: Material drawer icon]

Comment: Also note that the `drawer_shadow.9.png` provided in this download is specifically designed for the **left** edge. To get it to work with the right edge, you can simply rotate the one shadow image, using something like this in a `drawer_shadow_right.xml` file:

`<rotate android:drawable="@drawable/drawer_shadow" android:fromDegrees="180" android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:toDegrees="180" />`

Comment: I'm [having trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19724567/56285) getting this indicator to show up, [except for API level 18](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19727518/56285). Any ideas?