# How to add "menu" indicator next to Action Bar's app icon?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-icons, android-homebutton

At least Gmail and Youtube Android apps use a side menu ([navigation drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)?) that opens by swiping, or by clicking the app icon (home button):

[image]

Is the menu indicator / icon in the screenshot above a ready-made part of Android SDK? (Or a custom icon Google uses in their apps?) In any case, **what's the easiest way to get your home button to look like that**, i.e., like it opens a menu?

(`targetSdkVersion` 18; `minSdkVersion` 14)

### Resolution

Finally [got it working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19724694/56285). What was missing for me was 1) [the actual icon](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-nav-drawer-indicator.html) and 2) deferred call to `syncState()` on the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`.

Comment: Are you going to use `NavigationDrawer` or you just want the same look as in the picture? The drawer indicator is a custom icon which not only Google uses to indicate that pressing home button from the `ActionBar` will open a menu.

Comment: I'm already using `NavigationDrawer` *and* I want the same look as in the picture. :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To create similar implementation / look in your application you should use `ActionBarDrawerToggle` and set your custom icon as indicator next to ActionBar home button. For example :

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

private void setUpDrawerToggle(){
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                             /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
    // NB: required for the drawer indicator to show up!
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
```

Where `R.drawable.ic_drawer` is actually the icon to use as indicator. You can find it in [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html); see [**Navigation Drawer Indicator**](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-nav-drawer-indicator.html#theme=light&color=33b5e5,40).

References

1. [ActionBarDrawerToggle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html)
2. [Creating a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Comment: Ok, this is helpful. I already have `ActionBarDrawerToggle` with similar code; now I'm just looking for the right icon from the [icon pack](http://developer.android.com/downloads/design/Android_Design_Icons_20130926.zip)...

Comment: Any idea? There are no files named anything like "drawer" in the pack (`find . -name "*drawer*.png"` finds nothing).

Comment: You can get them from here too : http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-nav-drawer-indicator.html#theme=light&color=33b5e5%2C40

Comment: Great! That's what I needed. Can you edit that bit of info in the answer itself, and I'll accept it.

Comment: So, while this looks very promising, it's **not** enough to make the indicator show up, at least on my devices. :-/ [I found a way to make it work on API 18+](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19727518/56285), but below that remains an open question...

Comment: Check the edited answer.This code is tested on API LEVEL 14 and is working. If you are using Android Studio for development, you can create a new project with `NavigationDrawer` implemented and check the source code.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, I finally got it working. Curiously, `mDrawerLayout.post(... mDrawerToggle.syncState(); ... )` was the crucial thing missing from my code! (I'm editing out some irrelevant bits from your answer to make it cleaner.)

Comment: @Android-Developer : I have this similar problem, the 3 line icons is not animating when the drawer is opened: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829455/up-caret-is-not-animating-into-a-smaller-image-in-navigation-drawer

Comment: are you supposed to call `setUpDrawerToggle()` from the activities `onCreate`? should `mDrawerLayout` and `mDrawerToggle` just be class variables of said Activity? (i will update code if so)

Answer (score 10):

[Android-Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19724694/56285) and [HpTerm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19724642/56285) helped me in the right rirection, by

1. Pointing out this is indeed [NavigationDrawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) specific (which I was already using as in Google's example)
2. Telling where to find the `ic_drawer.png` icon (→ [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-nav-drawer-indicator.html#theme=light&color=33b5e5,40))

Now, unfortunately, creating ActionBarDrawerToggle like below seems **not** to be enough.
At least on my Nexus 7 (API 18) test device.

```
drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, 
                       drawerLayout, 
                       R.drawable.ic_navigation_drawer, 
                       R.string.side_menu_open, 
                       R.string.side_menu_closed) {
    // ...
};
```

### Partial solution (API level 18+)

I found one way to make the indicator show up though: **[`setHomeAsUpIndicator()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeAsUpIndicator%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)**. The downside: that method was added in API level 18.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // also required
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
        getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_navigation_drawer));
    }
}
```

So now the question remains: how to make this work (in my case) for API levels 14 through 17?

I verified on a 4.1.2 (API 16) device that the `ic_drawer` icon does **not** show up. With `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` I get the normal "home" icon (small arrow pointing left) and without it, the space left to my app icon remains blank.

### Final solution

Got it working using the edited version of [**Android-Developer's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19724694/56285).

Quite curiously, what was missing from my ActionBarDrawerToggle initialisation code was this:

```
   // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
   drawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });
```

With that included, calling `setHomeAsUpIndicator()` is **not** needed.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword here is [`NavigationDrawer`](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html); there's a full working code example on the Android developer site.

**READ THE END OF THE LINK GIVEN** : Open and Close with the App Icon

The following code is copied from there

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    ...

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
                ) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
          return true;
        }
        // Handle your other action bar items...

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    ...
}
```

Some files are available as download and the small 3 lines with the animation effect is fully exemplified.

You have to copy thoses files in the corresponding `drawable` folder. Depending on the theme you use, dark or light you have a different set of icons.

In my case I simply copied the `drawer_shadow.9.png` and `ic_drawer.png` in the drawable folder and followed the example and everything works just fine.

The icons are available in the link I provided, but they are **NOT** in the "Action Bar Icon Pack", **they are in the sample app** in the **corresponding res/drawable folders**.

Comment: I am already using NavigationDrawer. I'm looking for specific instructions on the easiest way to add that menu icon/indicator.

Comment: As I said the example given in the link gives all the details. Simply copy paste the example and it works. Have you taken a look at the example given by android developper ? I can copy paste it here but everything is in the downloadable example.

Comment: Where exactly did you find the `drawer_shadow.9.png` / `ic_drawer.png` files? The [Action Bar Icon Pack](http://developer.android.com/downloads/design/Android_Design_Icons_20130926.zip) linked to in Navigation Drawer documentaion doesn't seem to contain such files.

Comment: my mistake, they are in the "sample app" not in the action bar icon pack. If you download the sample app, go in the res/drawable folders. You'll find the icons there

Comment: Thanks! I indeed found them in the sample app. (Though I'm not sure drawer_shadow.9.png is relevant in my case.) The indicator can be found here too: http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-nav-drawer-indicator.html#theme=light&color=33b5e5%2C40

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I struggled a long time finding the icons and only found them in the sample app at the time I was looking for them. Thus, the link that @Android-Developer provided is useful.