# Navigation drawer doesn't show icon in actionbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, pagerslidingtabstrip

I have added navigation drawer to an activity which contains PagerSlidingStrip.I can see the navigation drawer when I slide from left to right of screen but I can't see navigation drawer icon in action bar.
Below is my code-

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:background="#8E58D4"
        app:pstsIndicatorColor="#5B349E"

        app:pstsDividerColor="#8E58D4"
        app:pstsTabSwitch="true"
      />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


</RelativeLayout>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: have you seen my answer

Comment: @Lokesh yeah..+one to ur answer.

Comment: You got the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
         ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar .setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
           actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

or

and use

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // also required
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
        getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_navigation_drawer));
    }
```

Comment: use actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

Comment: What is your app theme ?

Comment: plz check this link  if still you are not getting navigation icon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724567/how-to-add-menu-indicator-next-to-action-bars-app-icon

Comment: app theme-Theme.AppCompat

Answer (score 1):

add this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this for visible your menu icon.

```
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.menu);
```

and override onOptionsItemSelected like below for open drawer

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        //Open your drawer here
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Add the below code*

```
/**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

this may help you

Comment: it shows navigation drawer icon along with back icon..but does not open navigation drawer on clicking on icon

Answer (score 0):

remove this line, because this is causing your action bar to be non mutable

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

and have this

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

and change Action bar title by overriding this

```
@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}
```