# Adding Android studio main menu on actionbar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

Please give me an advise .How to add the menu icon(that three lines symbol) for an already created project. Also I wanna add the menu icon only for some layouts.
Please help
would be very thankful..[I mean this symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VekZI.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add "menu" indicator next to Action Bar's app icon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724567/how-to-add-menu-indicator-next-to-action-bars-app-icon)

Comment: Post your java and xml codes what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create menu in your application first create on Folder inside `res` directory named `menu`.

Then in `menu` create one file `main_menu.xml`

Add below code into `main_menu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:title="Item1" android:id="@+id/item1"></item>
    <item android:title="Item2" android:id="@+id/item2"></item>
</menu>
```

Here title which show in your menu.

To add menu in any activity put below code in your activity file.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the main_menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item1:
               //your action
                break;
            case R.id.item2:
                //your action
                break;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Brother Thanks for your reply.. Is this the hamburger Icon.? I meant the hamburger Icon.

Comment: No hamburger is for navigation drawer for menu it is three vertical dots.

Comment: Yes.. that's what I want. I have already created my project and I wanna add the hamburger icon to one layout..it's not the first layout. How can I do it? Thanks

Comment: You want to create menu or navigation drawer? First clear it. And for add menu in existing project to add the code in Activity file which i mention above

Comment: I wanna create a navigation drawer for one layout.. it should open when I click the hamburger Icon. :) I think it's clear now..Please help.and appreciate your help!

Comment: Android Studio automatically creates a NavigationDrawer Activity for you. Right-click and highlight the option to create a new activity. This will display the various types of activities you can use. Select NavigationDrawer Activity and the mainActivity, navDrawerFragment, activity_main.xml, and navdrawer.xml files will be created for you.

Comment: mmm yes.. but it opens new activity.. but I want to add this for already created activity. anyway I can do it since its just a single page know. thanks a lot for your help..

Comment: Hello brother, I need another help.I wanna know that can I use firebase as a database for every database purposes. I mean can I use firebase instead of sqlite?

Comment: Sqlite database is local database which is specific to particular device only. Firebase Realtime Database is nosql database which can access from any device and you can use it for any purpose. If you want to use RDBMS then you need to create one web service to access those database because android directly does not support database like mysql and oracle.

Comment: Hello brother. Sorry if I'm disturbing.I wanna add data into firebase database.then I wanna retrieve a summary of the added data that will show inside a button. when the button clicked the entire data should show. If you get my idea. please give me some advise.

Answer (score 0):

// enables the activity icon as a 'home' button.

```
 getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hamburger icon as in toolbar.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.wolfmatrix.dummy.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbarId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbarTextId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/backButtonIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_hamburger_icon_black_24dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: yes that's correct brother. Hamburger icon. I have already made the project in constraint layout. I want to add the hamburger icon in the third page of my project. Could you please help

Comment: How are you using this: as a drawer or something? I think if you want to include hamburger icon, then this helps you.

Comment: Yes as a drawer..Is there any other methods? Can I add hamburger Icon for any page by using this?

Comment: Use this third party library, simple and easy: https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

Comment: You can use above sample to include hambrger icon. You can find that icon in default from vector assets of android studio.

Comment: Brother which one should I have to download?

Comment: There is `menu` icon in the list in navigation section.

Comment: yes.. your code works.Great. but there are two action bars now. I mean the main action bar and a new bar with hamburger icon. what should I do?

Comment: In your style: use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

Comment: @Sam So, i help you then you probably know http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't know that.this is the first time I tried this, sorry for late. I'll vote for you :)

Comment: Hello brother, I need another help.I wanna know that can I use firebase as a database for every database purposes. I mean can I use firebase instead of sqlite?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Toolbar` in your layout `XML` then you can change `Home` icon as below:

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.hamburger_icon);
```